# Foreign keys - temporarily bypass?

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys

I have just started to learn about the pros of foreign keys in database design (mySQL / innoDB) and I wonder if there's any way to temporarily bypass the foreign key when doing a specific delete query, to just delete in the parent table, and not from the linked child tables.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to delete just in parent table - the linked child tables *should not* be linked. **However** you could set child tables' foreign key to "ON DELETE SET NULL" which would keep the items in child table, but they would no longer contain the reference to the deleted parent table item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOREIGN KEYs are supposed to keep the database consistent all the time. So it is against the very idea of foreign keys to have them in database and still let remove referenced rows…

Though… there is one case when temporarily breaking these constraints may make sense: during a transaction. Important thing is to have the database consistent before and after transaction and not to let any other database user see the inconsistent data, but during a transaction and only in the session doing the transaction, temporary inconsistency won't hurt. And SQL allows for this: you may define some foreign keys (and sometimes other constraints) deferrable and request deferring of enforcing them to the end of a transaction.

This way you may do a complicate set of changes on database, even removing some rows still references in other tables and still have the database consistent and the end of the transaction. Other database users won't even see the temporary inconsistency.

**Update:** It seems MySQL doesn't support deferred constraints. So this answer is probably not very useful.

Answer (score 6):

Do not even consider doing that, it will cause data integrity problems with your database. This is avery bad idea. The whole purpose of the foreign keys is to keep people from doing such a thing!

Comment: This is the response i was waiting to see.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ON DELETE SET NULL clause on the foreign key. That will allow you to delete rows in the parent table. The rows in the child table referring to the deleted rows in the parent table will have the foreign key column set to NULL.

Personally I have never really needed that functionality.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: It's very sad that you picked the wrong answer. This is truly a really terrible idea.

Comment: Yes, this is generally a bad idea. But I can imagine scenarios where this is usefull. Though, most scenatios where this is usefull should rather be solved using a relationship table.

Answer (score 0):

You can always issue a command to disable a particular key.  Other than that there is no way that I know about to bypass a constraint.  I'm guessing you are doing some batch load operations and need to disable the key for performance reasons?

Comment: What if he attempts to enable the foreign key on the child table that now has orphaned records? I think he will still have to drop the child records if he ever plans to enable the constraint with the missing parent record.

Comment: See my edit above.  He might be doing some massive batch loads in which case it can be beneficial for performance reasons to drop all keys/indexes/constraints, load the data, then run some procedure to ensure nothing is oprhaned and whatnot and then reenable everything.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the `DISABLE KEYS` doesn't bypass foreign key checks, only unique key checks.

To drop a foreign key constraint use:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> DROP FOREIGN KEY <constraintname>;
```

Then to restore the constraint, you need to re-declare the foreign key constraint in another `ALTER TABLE` statement.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html for details.

But I agree with @HLGEM and I give his answer +1.  Consider carefully if you really need to do this.  Most tasks are in fact *easier* if you retain foreign key constraints.

You can declare your foreign keys with cascading effects to set child table values to NULL or a DEFAULT value so you can delete parent rows.